# GET request with JSON body

Tags: javascript, rest, http, get

I know what I'm saying is a little weird, but I need to send JSON (or multipart), using GET request in JavaScript Client-Side. I want it in the body note in URL params.
Is there a way to accomplish this?.
Note: I don't have access to server side to change it to POST.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? And why didn't the other answers on StackOverflow work for you ?

Comment: Because there is no answer for this case.

Comment: I have tried ajax and xmlhttprequest, neither of them can send body with GET request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
'?body=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

While no limit in the spec, note that there is a practical maximum length to URLs in some browsers/libraries/etc, so hopefully your JSON isn't too long.

Comment: but this isn't the body it is query string

Comment: Fetch/curl/etc will not let you send body with GET. While it's technically allowed, ignored. Why would you want to do this? What site is accepting bodies in a GET request? :P